# how switch between mutiple appium sessions using ruby

Tags: appium

I want to test two chrome browsers on two different android devices, I have started two appium servers with two different ports. But when i started the second browser instance on the second device, the previous ( first device browser) session is killing.

Can anyone help me out of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Start two ports under the android settings in appium and also give the different bootstrap ports. This way you can run each browser on one port.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i have tried starting two ports but no luck. i have given completes details "https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/3592#issuecomment-54935074" please help on this